# Oracle SQL INNER Join based on non-matching values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, inner-join

```
ColA(Table1)     ColB(Table2)
AB3               AB_MNO_3
AB3               AB_PQR_3
AB4               AB_MNO_4
AB4               AB_PQR_4
```

I want to do `Inner Join` based on columns in two table with some of the non-equal values shown above. So, Table1 can have `AB3` which should be matched against `AB_MNO_3, AB_PQR_3` while `AB4` should be matched against `AB_MNO_4, AB_PQR_4`
Rest of the values in these columns in two tables do match. 
Would highly appreciate if anyone provides recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 tl INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
ON (tl.ColA = t2.ColB OR (tl.ColA ='AB3' AND t2.ColB='AB_MNO_3')
OR (tl.ColA ='AB3' AND t2.ColB='AB_PQR_3') OR (tl.ColA ='AB4' AND t2.ColB='AB_MNO_4')
OR (tl.ColA ='AB4' AND t2.ColB='AB_PQR_4'))
```

Answer (score 1):

From your examples : 
I assume that 
first two chars of colA and Colb equal
AND
last char of colA and ColB equal

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN
TABLE2 t2 ON 
substr(t1.ColA,0,2) =  substr(t2.ColB,0,2) 
AND
substr(t1.cola,length(t1.cola),1) = substr(t2.colb,length(t2.colb),1)
```